# Prove that there are at least $N$ distinct "absolute" differences between $N$ k-dimensional vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered the following problem:
Let's define $h(a, b) = (|a_1 - b_1|, |a_2 - b_2|, ..., |a_k - b_k|)$, where $a$ and $b$ are two k-dimensional vectors with natural numbers and $a = (a_1, ..., a_k)$ and $b = (b_1, ..., b_k)$, $|x -y|$ is the absolute difference between $x$ and $y$. Now we have to prove the following:

Given $n$ different vectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$, consider $A = \{h(a_i, a_j) |1 \leq i, j \leq n \}$. Prove that $|A| \geq n$, in other words that the number of different values of $h$ among all pairs of vectors is at least $n$. Note that we count $o = (0, 0, ..) = h(a_1, a_1)$ as one of these values.

What I have tried:
As my linear algebra isn't very good(and I'm also not sure if such operation as $h$ is "standard" as for ex. dot product), I tried proving the statement with induction on the dimensions of these vectors. The case where they are $1$-dimensional is pretty straightforward, the vectors are just integers, we can sort them in increasing order, then $|a_1 - a_i|$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ has $n$ different values. However, I'm not sure how to continue. I would be glad if somebody could help me. I'm interested in other approaches also. Please note that we are talking about absolute difference here, if it were normal difference I have already solved it.

Comment: Are the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Comment: No, they are in $\mathbb{N}^k$.